# CSS Issue for Firefox (extra padding)

Tags: css, firefox, margin, padding

Hi I am building a store on Volusion, and can't figure this problem out. The issue is that in IE, Chrome, Safari, my padding for search_refinement_filters is looking fine, but in Firefox, they are being pushed about 350 px to the right.  [Check out the Firefox CSS issue here](http://zsvae.zbfps.servertrust.com/category-s/3112.htm)

Please let me know if you can help! I have tried moving search_refinement_filters from the content div to content area, but unfortunately I wasn't able to configure that to work either.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add following styles to your `#search_refinement_filters` div. Remove others.

```
#search_refinement_filters {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 232px;
  width: 700px;
}
```

And then apply `position: relative` to your `#content` div.

```
#content {
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I was able to fix it with your code. Thank you so much! So many odd adjustments needed to be done to override volusion that it had my head in a spin.

Answer (score 2):

It's due to the left padding and left margin on `#search_refinement_filters`. You also have some weirdness with the absolute positioning. You may want to add `position: relative` to `#content`.

Take a look at [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/). It is a convenient tool for analyzing code in Firefox.

Comment: Might want to mention that Firefox has a quite powerful set of baked in development/inspection tools that render Firebug sort of extraneous.

Comment: Thanks! I actually have it and used it, but what I was trying WAS NOT working haha. Anyway, thank you greatly for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

As 2C-B said #search_refinement_filters has left padding and left margin. These can be removed or overridden to prevent the issue with the styling.

You should definitely get Firebug for Testing purposes if you don't already have it.

Get it here: https://getfirebug.com/

It is an invaluable tool for debugging html, css, and javascript problems.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah I figured I was over-doing it. Nice and cleaned up now :)